# Error al validar formulario utilizando php y javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario para editar una publicación generada anteriormente por un usuario. Al mostrarle esta misma información al usuario a la hora de permitirle la edición, recurro al uso de PHP para traer desde la base de datos la información alli alojada para que el usuario sepa lo que envió en una primera instancia y pueda modificarlo desde este nuevo formulario.

Mi problema surge ya que necesito una forma de validar el botón de submit de este formulario para que en caso de que no haya ningún cambio (es decir, los datos del nuevo formulario son iguales a los ya alojados en la base de datos), el formulario no se envie, sino que aparezca un sweetalert informandole al usuario que no realizó ninguna modificación.

Lo que sucede es que la función JS que desarrollé para este objetivo no se ejecuta correctamente ya que no puedo llamar a PHP desde javascript, y necesito hacerlo para validar y que los datos que el usuario envía correspondan con los de la base de datos.

Adjunto mi código hasta el momento:

```
<?php
    $CantShow=10;
        $compag = (int)(!isset($_GET['publishpShow'])) ? 1 : $_GET['publishpShow'];
        $TotalReg = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM anuncios");
        $totalr = mysqli_num_rows($TotalReg);
        $TotalRegistro = ceil($totalr/$CantShow);
        $IncNum = (($compag +1)<=$TotalRegistro)?($compag +1):0;
        $consult = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM anuncios WHERE id = '$id' ORDER BY id_pub DESC LIMIT ".(($compag-1)*$CantShow)." , ".$CantShow);
        //$consultA = mysqli_query($conexion, $consult);
    ?>
    <div class="publishmShow">
        <?php
        while($lista = mysqli_fetch_array($consult)){
                $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $lista['id']);
                $usuariob = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$userid'");
                $use = mysqli_fetch_array($usuariob);
        ?>
                <div class="publishContainer">
                    <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
                        <div class="publishannouncer" id="publishannouncer">
                            <h3>Editar mi anuncio</h3>
                            <form name="publishform" class="publishform"  method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                                <div name="publish" class="contenedor-inputs">
                                    <div class="secondthree">
                                        <div class="currency">
                                            <p>Moneda</p>
                                            <div class="currencyselector">
                                                <select name="currency" id="currency" onchange="show_moneda();">
                                                    <option value="0" selected disabled><?php echo $lista['moneda'];?></option>   
                                                    <option value="1">Dólar estadounidense (USD)</option>                                
                                                    <option value="2">Bitcoin (BTC)</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Ethereum (ETH)</option>
                                                    <option value="4">Binance Coin (BNB)</option>
                                                    <option value="5">Cardano (ADA)</option>
                                                    <option value="6">Dogecoin (DOGE)</option>
                                                    <option value="7">XRP (XRP)</option>
                                                    <option value="8">Polkadot (DOT)</option>
                                                    <option value="9">Uniswap (UNI)</option>
                                                    <option value="10">Litecoin (LTC)</option>
                                                    <option value="11">Chainlink (LINK)</option>
                                                    <option value="12">Tether (USDT)</option>
                                                    <option value="13">USD Coin (USDC)</option>
                                                    <option value="14">Binance USD (BUSD)</option>
                                                    <option value="15">DAI (DAI)</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                                    function show_moneda(){
                                                        var currency = document.getElementById('currency');
                                                        var currencyselected = currency.options[currency.selectedIndex].text;
                                                        document.getElementById("currencyselected").value = currencyselected;
                                                        console.log(currencyselected);
                                                    }
                                                </script>
                                                <input type="hidden" id="currencyselected" name="currencyselected" value=" "></input>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="quantfeecontainer">
                                            <div class="quantity">
                                                <p>Cantidad</p>
                                                <div class="quantityselector">
                                                    <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantIndicator" value="<?php echo $lista['cantidad'];?>" step="0.1" min="0">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="fee">
                                                <div class="feeptitle modified">
                                                    <p>Porcentaje de Comisión</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="feeselector">
                                                    <input type="number" name="fee" id="feeIndicator" value="<?php echo $lista['comision'];?>" step="0.1" min="0">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="actionbuttons">
                                    <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-volver">Volver</a>
                                    <input type="submit" id="confirmar" name="confirmar" class="btn-confirm" value="Actualizar">
                                </div>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    function validateForm() {
                                        var currency = document.forms["publishform"]["currency"].value;
                                        var quantity = document.forms["publishform"]["quantity"].value;
                                        var fee = document.forms["publishform"]["fee"].value;
                                        if (currency == "<?php $lista['moneda'];?>" || quantity == "<?php $lista['cantidad'];?>" || fee == "<?php $lista['comision'];?>") {
                                            setTimeout(function () {
                                            swal("¡Ups!","Parece que hay opciones sin seleccionar. Por favor completá todos los campos para poder publicar tu anuncio.","error", {button: "Intentar de nuevo",})
                                            }, 200);
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                </script>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Entiendo que quizá podría utilizar AJAX pero realmente no estoy muy seguro de ello. ¿Alguna idea? Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Este es el típico problema que debería resolverse con Ajax o con la nueva API fetch sin ninguna duda. En cuanto a la redacción de la pregunta, se agradece que uses correctamente el punto y coma. Un párrafo enorme es fatigoso a la vista.

Comment: Ya actualicé el párrafo para que se adapte mejor visualmente. Gracias por el consejo. Respecto a lo que mencionas de Ajax o la API fetch, tienes idea como podría implementarlo o donde conseguir algo mas de ayuda al respecto?

Comment: Aquí mismo hay varias preguntas / respuestas sobre Ajax y/o sobre la API Fetch que pueden servirte de guía. También en la red hay varios tutoriales. Puedes revisar, cuando entiendas los conceptos básicos intenta un código si hay algún problema concreto sobre ese código te ayudaremos aquí a resolverlo.

Comment: Aquí tienes [documentación sobre Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX), y aquí tienes [doc sobre Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Te aconsejo que trates primero de entender los conceptos básicos de lo que allí se explica para que no andes dando palos de ciego con el código. Una vez entendido cómo funciona verás lo fácil que es lograr lo que quieres aquí: comunicar entre cliente y servidor sin recargas de página ni nada por el estilo. Ajax se usa mucho con jQuery así que no te sorprendas si encuentras muchos ejemplos basados en jQuery.

Comment: Muchas gracias.